# Why does Python replace an earlier defined Pandas dataframe with it's later adjusted copy?

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Python, and want to make a copy (`x2`) of an existing Pandas dataframe (`x1`), and adjust all existing values to another value (or set them to e.g. `NaN`). This was attempted as follows:

```
x1    = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2,3], 'y':[4,5,6]}) 
x2    = x1 
x2[:] = 5 
x1
```

After redefining all values of `x2` by 5, however, `x1` also gets redefined. This behavior of redefinition of existing variables is highly unwanted. Why is this happening and how could it be prevented? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is how any object works in Python. Assignment isn't a copy like it is in C++. Use `x1.copy()`.

Comment: There is no copy being created anywhere. `x2    = x1` does not make a copy. **Assignment never copies anything in python** " This behavior of redefinition of existing variables is highly unwanted." Nothing is being *redefined*.

Comment: Although not about pandas exactly, you should read the following: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html it applies to all Python objects. Read it and learn to understand Python on its own terms, instead of trying to apply semantics from other languages (guessing C or C++) to Python.

Comment: Thanks juanpa.arrivillaga and ggorlen for the elaborations and references for further reading!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saying `x2 = x1` makes `x2` point to the same object as `x1`. In order to prevent that from happening, you need to make a copy of `x1` and assign that to `x2`.

Try `x2 = x1.copy()`

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks for the quick help!